# Disable button on selecting specific dropdown value in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have to disable button when i select a particular value in dropdown. But, it is not working on changing the dropdown value. Initially , the button is disable when the select button value is "Select the report" and on changing select value , the button is enabled. However, when i again change the select value to "select the report", the button is in enable state and not in disable state.

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    reports: [],
    selectedReport: '',
    isLoading:true,
    reportSelected:false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  
    let url ="API";
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    trackPromise(
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let reportsFromAPI = data.map( report => {
        return {value: report, display: report}
      })
      this.setState({
        reports:[{value:'', display: 'Select the report'}].concat(reportsFromAPI),
        isLoading: false,
        reportSelected:false
      })
 
  
    )}
render() {
    return (
     
        
      //{ !this.state.isLoading && 
      <div>
        <Header></Header>
        <LoadingIndicator/>
        <br />
        <div class="container">
        { !this.state.isLoading && 
          <div class="row">
            <div className="col-sm-8">
              <div>
               <select value={this.state.selectedReport} onChange={(e) =>  this.setState({ selectedReport: e.target.value},
                  ()=> {
                   if(this.state.selectedReport!=="Select the report")
                     {
                                 this.setState({ reportSelected: true})
                     }
                     else{
                                 this.setState({ reportSelected:false})
                     }
                   }
                   ) }>
                  {this.state.reports.map((report) => <option key={report.value} value={report.value}>{report.display}</option>)}
                </select>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-4">
              <button type="button" disabled={!this.state.reportSelected} class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.downloadReport}> Run Report</button>
            </div>
  


          </div>
         }
        </div>
      </div>
     // }

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedReport` state value is never be `Select the report` for all options you have. And for option as you predefined is empty, you need set it to `Select the report`

```js
reports:[{
  value:'Select the report', 
  display: 'Select the report'}]
.concat(reportsFromAPI),
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I set the value as "Select the report" in reports arraylist .But still the button state is not changed to disable.